# clouddformation creation failed, Maximum number of simultaneous requests reached

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I got the following in the CloudFormation events panel when creating a large stack. It's on an RDS resource, and caused the stack creation to fail:

> Maximum number of simultaneous requests reached. Please consider adding a retry mechanism or increasing the queue size.

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rate-limiting error from Amazon. It probably occurs on other resources, but it definitely happens on RDS creation because **only one RDS instance can be created at a time**. In other words, if your stack includes two databases, they can't be created in parallel.

To work around this, [make one database depend on the other](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html). In other words, use `DependsOn: databaseA` on the databaseB resource. That will ensure database A is created before database B creation begins.